# How to pass authentication between applications on same domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

We have a requirement for users to be authenticated once they login to root application without having to enter credentials again. apps are all on same do

domain.com/site1
domain.com/site2

All of the applications are written in webforms and mvc none in .net core, I have researched and found using machine keys and cross app redirects will help with  this, **however how can I pass a session variable such as user email to load the roles in site 2 from site 1** any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" requireSSL="true" 
      protection="All" 
      enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I think you can check the Oauth2 protocol : https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: Can you please refer any code samples that might help me with this implementation?

Comment: You can't share session variables between apps. If you're using mvc identity you can use claims to add the value you want to pass between apps

Comment: Thanks will give it a try, thanks for the guidance

Comment: I suggest you use a cookie, create a cookie which contains username + salt/ecret key and this encrypted secret key and the encryption keys are with both applications Any request from user will carry this cookie so if the cookie contains a username, other application trusts user is logged in on other application.